# How do you fix NullPointExceptions?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I have been coding a social app using **Kotlin**. Recently I added a find friends fragment to my Main activity(Main activity has three fragments: home page, deny/accept friend request, and find friends where you can send friend requests). In addition, Main Activity has a tab layout where it is above all fragments and has a button that directs the users to a profile page. This is where the problem occurs. When I try to sign out the user using:

```
    mAuth!!.signOut()
    startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, LoginActivity::class.java))
    finishAffinity()
```

I get an error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.realtimechat.findfriends.FindFriendsFragment$onViewCreated$1.onCancelled(FindFriendsFragment.kt:104)
```

But this error is only present when I visit the FindFriends Fragment before clicking on the profile page button to redirect the app to profile page where I can sign out. For example, if I start the app (which starts with a home fragment) and go to the profile page right away to sign out, the error is gone and I am successfully signed out and redirected to the log in page. However, if I start the app, go to find friends fragment and then go to the profile page to log out, I get the error. Is there something I am doing wrong?

(By the way, find friends has a recycler view)

**FindFriendsFragment.kt**

```
package com.example.realtimechat.findfriends

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.realtimechat.R
import com.example.realtimechat.common.Constants
import com.example.realtimechat.common.NodeNames
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import java.lang.NullPointerException

class FindFriendsFragment: Fragment() {

    private var rvFindFriends: RecyclerView? = null
    private var findFriendsAdapter: FindFriendAdapter? = null
    private var findFriendsModelList: MutableList<FindFriendModel> = ArrayList()
    private var tvEmptyFriendsList: TextView? = null

    private var databaseReference: DatabaseReference? = null
    private var currentUser: FirebaseUser? = null
    private var progressBar: View? = null

    private var databaseReferenceFriendRequests: DatabaseReference? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_friends, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        rvFindFriends = view.findViewById(R.id.rvFindFriends)
        tvEmptyFriendsList = view.findViewById(R.id.tvEmptyFriendsList)
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)

        rvFindFriends!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        findFriendsModelList = ArrayList()
        findFriendsAdapter = FindFriendAdapter(activity!!, findFriendsModelList)
        rvFindFriends!!.adapter = findFriendsAdapter

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(NodeNames.USERS);
        currentUser  = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser;

        databaseReferenceFriendRequests = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(NodeNames.FRIEND_REQUESTS).child(currentUser!!.uid);

        tvEmptyFriendsList!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
        progressBar!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE;

        val query: Query = databaseReference!!.orderByChild(NodeNames.USERNAME)
        query.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
                findFriendsModelList.clear()

                for(ds: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                    val userId = ds.key
                    if(userId.equals(currentUser?.uid)){
                        continue
                    }

                    if(ds.child(NodeNames.USERNAME).value !=null){
                        val username = ds.child(NodeNames.USERNAME).value.toString()
                        val photoFileName = ds.child(NodeNames.PHOTO).value.toString()

                        databaseReferenceFriendRequests!!.child(userId!!).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
                            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                if(snapshot.exists()){
                                    val requestType = snapshot.child(NodeNames.REQUEST_TYPE).value.toString()
                                    if(requestType == Constants.REQUEST_STATUS_SENT){
                                        findFriendsModelList.add(FindFriendModel(userId, photoFileName, username, true))
                                        findFriendsAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    findFriendsModelList.add(FindFriendModel(userId, photoFileName, username, false))
                                    findFriendsAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                }
                            }

                            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                                progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
                            }
                        })
                        progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
                        tvEmptyFriendsList?.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                try {
                    progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed to fetch friend list ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }catch (e: NullPointerException){
                    throw(IllegalAccessException(e.message))
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**FindFriendsAdapter.kt**

```
package com.example.realtimechat.findfriends

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException
import com.example.realtimechat.R
import com.example.realtimechat.common.Constants
import com.example.realtimechat.common.NodeNames
import com.example.realtimechat.requests.RequestsFragment
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage


class FindFriendAdapter(private val context: Context,
                        private val findFriendModelList: List<FindFriendModel> = mutableListOf()) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FindFriendAdapter.FindFriendViewHolder>() {


    private var friendRequestDatabase: DatabaseReference? = null
    private var currentUser: FirebaseUser? = null
    private var userId: String? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FindFriendAdapter.FindFriendViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_find_friends_layout, parent, false)
        return FindFriendViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FindFriendAdapter.FindFriendViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val friendModel = findFriendModelList[position]
        holder.tvUsername.text = friendModel.username

        val fileRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(Constants.IMAGES_FOLDER + "/" + friendModel.photoFileName!!.substring(friendModel.photoFileName!!.lastIndexOf("/")+1))
        fileRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {uri ->
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(uri)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profileicon)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_profileicon)
                .into(holder.ivProfile)
        }

        friendRequestDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(NodeNames.FRIEND_REQUESTS)
        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        if(friendModel.requestSent!!){
            holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }else{
            holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        holder.btnSendRequest.setOnClickListener {
            holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            userId = friendModel.userId

            friendRequestDatabase!!.child(currentUser!!.uid).child(userId!!).child(NodeNames.REQUEST_TYPE).setValue(Constants.REQUEST_STATUS_SENT)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if(task.isSuccessful){
                        friendRequestDatabase!!.child(userId!!).child(currentUser!!.uid).child(NodeNames.REQUEST_TYPE)
                            .setValue(Constants.REQUEST_STATUS_RECEIVED)
                            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                if(task.isSuccessful){
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Request sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                    holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                    holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                    holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                }
                            }.addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to send request ${exception.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                            }
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to send request ${exception.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                }
        }

        holder.btnCancelRequest.setOnClickListener {
            holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            userId = friendModel.userId

            friendRequestDatabase!!.child(currentUser!!.uid).child(userId!!).child(NodeNames.REQUEST_TYPE).setValue(null)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if(task.isSuccessful){
                        friendRequestDatabase!!.child(userId!!).child(currentUser!!.uid).child(NodeNames.REQUEST_TYPE)
                            .setValue(null)
                            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                if(task.isSuccessful){
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Request cancelled successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                    holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                    holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                }
                            }.addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to cancel request ${exception.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                                holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            }
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to cancel request ${exception.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    holder.btnSendRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.pbRequest.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.btnCancelRequest.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return findFriendModelList.size
    }

    inner class FindFriendViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val ivProfile: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivProfilePic)
        val tvUsername: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsername)
        val btnSendRequest: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnSendRequest)
        val btnCancelRequest: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelRequest)
        val pbRequest: ProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pbRequest)

    }
}
```

**The error code is directing me to this part of the code:**

```
override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                try {
                    progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed to fetch friend list ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }catch (e: NullPointerException){
                    throw(IllegalAccessException(e.message))
                }
            }
```

**Specifically, this:**

```
throw(IllegalAccessException(e.message))
```

**However, the original code was:**

```
override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed to fetch friend list ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
```

**And the error directed me to**

```
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed to fetch friend list ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Any help/solutions to this issue will be greatly appreciated!!

***UPDATE***
I deleted the Toast from the `override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError)` and the code works perfectly normal. However, I need this Toast to be apparent, so is there a way around this?

Comment: `databaseReferenceFriendRequests` may be Null and causing problem

Comment: @chandmohd how would I fix that?

Comment: @chandmohd I have added a condition `if(databaseReferenceFriendRequests!=null)` , but the error was still present, so I do not think this is the solution

Comment: Generally, you should avoid using `var` and `nullable` types. And if you do, guard them with `null` checks. Skimming your code, I can't find a reason for you to even have `nullable` types. If you get rid of it completely, you will not have any `null-pointer exceptions`.

Comment: Don't use `!!` unless you know for sure something can't be null. It is usually unnecessary to ever use it.

Comment: I have removed all the unnecessary `nullable` objects. However, the `error` is still apparent

Answer (score 0):

So I have came up with a possible solution (it works but I am uncertain if it is the best option):

I have basically added the condition:

```
if(isRemoving) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to fetch friend requests: ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Again, if you have a better solution, it would be very appreciated!